# Copying all *.md to specific dir (ruby)

Tags: ruby, expression

I'm trying out to copy all *.md files from a directory to another.
With that code:

```
project = Hoe::Manns.get_projectname
dest = "#{Dir.home}/RubymineProjects/#{project}"
wikipath = "#{Dir.home}/RubymineProjects/#{project}.wiki"
FileUtils.mkdir_p "#{dest}/doc", verbose: true if !File.exist?('doc')  
files = Dir.glob("#{wikipath}/*.md")
FileUtils.cp "#{files}", "#{dest}/doc", verbose: true
```

i'm getting

cp ["/home/sascha/RubymineProjects/hoe-manns.wiki/home.md", "/home/sascha/RubymineProjects/hoe-manns.wiki/behind-the-scene.md"] /home/sascha/RubymineProjects/hoe-manns/doc
rake aborted!

Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - ["/home/sascha/RubymineProjects/hoe-manns.wiki/home.md", "/home/sascha/RubymineProjects/hoe-manns.wiki/behind-the-scene.md"]

Maybe i missed anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FileUtils.cp` can take a single filename or an **array** of filenames as its first argument. Try this:

```
FileUtils.cp files, "#{dest}/doc", verbose: true
```